# EZSheets Module won't open Window to log into Google account

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm learning Python using Automate the Boring Stuff and I am currently on [Chapter 14](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter14/) which centers on using EZSheets to work with Google Sheets.

The book says to place the credentials-sheets.json file in the same folder as the Python scripts, so I placed it in the "\Python38\Scripts" folder.

The next step is to run import ezsheets and it will open a new browser window for me to log in to my Google account. Here is where I am stuck. Importing EZSheets does nothing. I don't get any errors, but it doesn't open the window for me to log into my Google account.

All the code I used was:

```
import ezsheets
```

Comment: One of the best things to do when you get stuck using some library is to look for the official documentation. Googling ezsheets brings up the documentation site: https://ezsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

That documentation gives a url where you go to do the account authorization.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent about the last 2 hours tackling this problem. As someone with a thin layer of SQL and Python experience...I was very frustrated with your same problem. Here's what I did when I got stuck in a couple places.

It might just be that you need to change the directory you are working in to "\Python38\Scripts" and then run the script, like you mentioned. If not, here's what I did next.

I followed the [ezsheets doc's](https://ezsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), much like you, except I skipped over the [Google Python Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python/) linked in the doc. No problem, I circled back and found it.

"Setting up the Same" was my next issue. First problem there: the documentation says to name your credentials "credentials-sheets.json" while the Google quickstart.py file calls for "credentials.json". You have to change that in the quickstart.py file (and quickstart.py should be in the same file location as the credentials. In your case: "\Python38\Scripts").

Look for this
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
'credentials-sheets.json', SCOPES)

The above is what I fixed in the quickstart.py file (to be the same as the ezsheets documentation) and worked for me.

Then, I was getting a 400 error when running Quickstart. The browser window would open and it would give me this Authorization Error: "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch". It specified that I did not have the right redirect URL authorized. Stumped me for a while but if you can get to [your developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector2/apis/credentials) and edit the credentials, you can add the local host location and the port number given to you in the error.

Here comes the final issue with that solution. In the quickstart, "port:0" was specified and it would randomize every time I added the most recent port number to the authorization. After adding 3-4 ports and having it change on me, I saw in the quickstart.py file that I needed to specify the port like so.

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
```

After changing that in the quickstart.py file and adding that to my "Authorized redirect URI's" in Developer Console, I was able to finish this step and move on.

I'm open to criticism if this is incorrect. I found those two errors were missing from every answer I came across. Hopefully this saves some people some time while trying to setup ezsheets to sync with Google Drive and Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

For the import command to work you must first type python or python3 to your command prompt while inside the directory you want to import ezsheets Once you have the python prompt then import ezsheets command will work